# Running .NET Framework web app in IIS Express in Docker container of Windows Server 2016 - does not have write access to temporary ASP.NET Files

Tags: asp.net, docker, iis-express, windows-server

I have a .NET Framework web app that runs fine in IIS Express on my local machine. I have created a Docker for Windows container with Windows Server 2016 running in it in which I've installed:
- IIS Express
- the .net framework web app

When I run the web app in IIS Express (I do not want to use full IIS) in the container, and then, also in the container, send requests to it using curl, I get a 500 response with the error: 
  The current identity (User Manager\ContainerAdministrator) does not have write access to 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files'

I haven't found a solution to this yet. Has anyone tried this or have a suggestion?

Comment: Why not use IIS (non-Express) within the Docker container?

Comment: Microsoft won't support any production usage of IIS Express. So please re-consider your statement of "I do not want to use full IIS".

Comment: The reason I'm using IIS Express is because of a particular need to kick off the web app in IIS Express via our custom tool. We do some profiling of the app in the process. We want it to be used from a developer's workstation without having to have full IIS installed.

Comment: After more thought, I think it might be best to have our custom tool be flexible enough to run an app with either IIS Express or IIS. I would still like to figure out the workaround or fix for getting IIS Express to work in Server container though.